# How do I append an HTML string to the DOM

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a data table with data from a JSON file.

I filtered the data and generated an HTML string that I need prepended to this

```
 <div class='toolbar'>
```

I am having issues with prepending it.

```
 $(document).find(cleanKey).prepend(htmlString) // didnt work

 $('#' + key.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "-") + '-table').prepend(htmlString) // didnt work
```

Comment: try `$(".toolbar").prepend($(htmlString))`

Answer (score 1):

Are you prepending or appending?

**Prepend**

```
$('.toolbar').prepend(htmlString);
```

**Append**

```
$('.toolbar').append(htmlString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append a string with the following:

```
$('#' + key.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "-") + '-table').html() += htmlString;
```